# yadcf - multi_select with select2 - options dropdown not case sensitive

Tags: datatables, yadcf

Will be posible, in yadcf multi_select filter, sort possible option with case insensibility?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgutbor/m26jzxsf/) to explain this.

In column STATUS are 4 possible values: "abs", "off", "OFF" and "ON". In dropdown the options appears in this order: "OFF", "ON", "abs", "off". And my desire is the options appears in this order:  "abs", "OFF", "off", "ON".

```
Thanks in advance one more time.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide you own custom sort function, , use the following attributes for the column `sort_as: 'custom', sort_as_custom_func: mySort` (where mySort is a sorting function, like this

```
'use strict';

var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
var mySort = function(a, b) {
return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
};
yadcf.init(oTable, [
    {
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: 'multi_select',
        filter_match_mode: 'exact',
        select_type: 'select2',
        sort_as: 'custom',
        sort_as_custom_func: mySort
    },{
        column_number: 1,
        filter_type: 'text',
    }
]);
```

[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/m26jzxsf/17/)

Comment: Really thanks again for your solution. As the other, works like a charm.

Comment: Having a similar problem which driving me nuts.. Two columns, one for month name and one for weekday, want my two select lists to sort Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr and Mon,Tue, Wed etc. tried numerous ways and the closes with custom sort will show 1,2,3 etc. in the select list instead of the month name. Please advise as the docs are very limited when it comes to custom_sort. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Webkungen, please open a new Q' and provide jsfiddle link for your test case

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052386/datatables-yadcf-and-filter-sort-order Thank you!