# Datatables / YADCF and filter sort order

Tags: filter, datatables, yadcf

I'm using datatables and yadcf to filter on month and weekday, but cannot get the sorting right for the select lists.

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Weekday</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

```js
var myData = [
    {"Id":1,"Name":"Test 1","Month":{"Id":5,"Label":"May"},"Weekday":{"Id":3,"Label":"Tuesday"}},
    {"Id":2,"Name":"Test 2","Month":{"Id":5,"Label":"May"},"Weekday":{"Id":3,"Label":"Tuesday"}}
    ...
];

$(function () {
    var Table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        'data': myData,
        "columns" : [
            { "targets": 0, "data" : "Id" },
            { "targets": 1, "data" : "Name" },
            { "targets": 2, "data": function ( data, type, val, meta ) {
                if (type === 'display') {
                    return  data.Month.Label;

                }else if (type === 'filter') {
                    return data.Month.Label;
                }
                // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
                return data.Month.Id;
            } },
            { "targets": 3, "data": function ( data, type, val, meta ) {
                if (type === 'display') {
                    return  data.Weekday.Label;

                }else if (type === 'filter') {
                    return data.Weekday.Label;
                }
                // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
                return data.Weekday.Id;
            } }
        ]
    });

    yadcf.init(Table, [
        {
            column_number : 2, 
            filter_type: 'select',
            filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
            style_class: 'form-control'
        },
        {
            column_number : 3, 
            filter_type: 'select',
            filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
            style_class: 'form-control'
        }
    ]);
} );
```

[image: Filter select does not order]

How do I order these filters so they order January, February, March and the weekdays Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc.?

*Fiddle:*
https://jsfiddle.net/Webkungen/jLq6okgc/2/

If I add a custom sort function for the filter and return **data.Month.Id** for the filter the sorting will be right but then the month number is shown in the filter instead of it's name.

Appreciate any help on this as it's driving me crazy, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the  `sort_as: 'custom',` `sort_as_custom_func: monthSort`
And implement your own sorting function, here is a quick way:

```
$(function () {
    var Table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        'data': myData,
        "columns" : [
            { "data" : "Id" },
            { "data" : "Name" },
            { "data" : "Month.Label" },
            { "data" : "Weekday.Label" }
        ]
    });

    yadcf.init(Table, [
        {
            column_number : 2, 
            filter_type: 'select',
            filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
            style_class: 'form-control',
            sort_as: 'custom',
            sort_as_custom_func: monthSort
        },
        {
            column_number : 3, 
            filter_type: 'select',
            filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
            style_class: 'form-control'
        }
    ]);
  
  function monthSort(a, b){
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
         return months.indexOf(a) - months.indexOf(b);}
} );
```

[Here a link to a working test page](https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/oxLdz8sh/)

Comment: Thanks, works fine for the months but can't figure how to do with the weekdays, on my dev server which is in English weekdays work fine, but on production where it's localized (Swedish in the case) the order is Sunday, Tuesday, Monday. I don't really understand the logic of the custom sort function?

Comment: Ahh sorry the confusion, has nothing to do with number of month/weekday. I changed to the server is serving the localized name, and the corresponding array in the custom function now it works on both servers. Thank you!